# Simple constraint programming solver

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, mathematical-optimization, constraint-programming

I'm trying to get familiar with constraint programming.

All documentation/videos I've seen so far just contain description of top-level concepts and code examples based on CP-libraries utilization (like Choko, Gecode, JaCoP etc).

I'd like to implement at least something simple in Java without any libraries.

Are there any resources where I can find working code in Java/C#/C++/Python which implements main CP ideas? (at least "send more money" problem solution).

(or, maybe, if somebody can explain it here, it would be great).

Comment: Coursera? Isn't there a tab on the course page that links to some optimization tools? https://class.coursera.org/optimization-001/wiki/view?page=tools

Comment: @ZiyaoWei: yeap. But what's the point? What can I learn from `engine.addConstraint(a); engine.addConstraint(b); print(engine.solve());` ?

Comment: Isn't CHOCO open source?

Comment: @ZiyaoWei: I made an attempt to investigate JaCoP sources. They're huge. It's like trying to understand how to send 'Hello' over a network from looking at Apache sources.

Comment: If you want to implement something, why do you need working code?

Comment: The Coursera class linked by Ziyao Wei has good lectures on CP that explain the basic ideas of branching and propagating. Maybe you could implement something simple based on this - integer domain store and _only_ constraints of the form x != y.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on what are you trying to do.

1- If you want to get started with Constraint Programming (CP) tools, you need first to understand modelling in this approach. For that, you have be able to define a given problem as a set of constraints then you post your model to a solver (that already knows how to deal with these constraints).

I personally find the G12_MiniZinc_Distribution (available via http://www.minizinc.org/) and its latest tutorial a very good way to start (the latest distribution cames with a lot of models). There is also online models if you want to see how a CP model looks like (w.r.t minizinc syntax) : http://www.hakank.org/minizinc.

2- If you have an advanced theoretical understanding of CP, you may directly see the implementation of some techniques (e.g. propagators) from available libraries since developing a CP Solver from scratch is (IMO) a foolish idea. 
These are some open-source solvers/libraries : G12, Choco, Mistral, Or-Tools.

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, the [OptaPlanner](https://www.optaplanner.org/) (open source, java) documentation has a **in depth explanation of a few algorithms**, such as [Simulated Annealing](http://docs.optaplanner.org/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/#simulatedAnnealing) and [Tabu Search](http://docs.optaplanner.org/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/#tabuSearch).

Here's an image from there:

[image: Simulated Annealing]

Answer (score 0):

If there is still someone look for something like this:

You might want to check out [Minicp](http://minicp.org)
where you can find slides and it's a solver written in Java.

If you want to write your own solver from scratch in a high level but fast programming language please check out my blog series:
[ConstraintSolver.jl blog posts](https://opensourc.es/blog/constraint-solver-1)